# How to take a whole line as input using vector in c++?

Tags: c++, vector

**Example:-Animals ( Reptiles Birds ( Eagles Pigeons Crows ) ) as input? **

## I am not getting the answer for this input Animals ( Reptiles Birds ( Eagles Pigeons Crows ) )

```
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#define ll long long 
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
ll n,m,k,cb=0,ob=0;
cin>>n;
string c;
vector<string> s;
while(cb!=ob)
{
    cin>>c;
    if(c=="(")
    ob++;
    else if(c==")")
    cb++;
    s.push_back(c);
}
for(ll i=0;i<s.size();i++)
cout<<s[i];

return 0;
}
```

Comment: [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Comment: Actually, I can't really tell what you are asking. Can you please try to clarify with a more detailed description of the problem. Please include your input, along with the output you want, and the output you actually get.

Answer (score 0):

First problem is that the first thing you read is a `long long` value. `Animal` just isn't.

You are checking for `while(cb!=ob)`. Some lines above `cb` and `ob` are both initialized with `0`. so your loop will never run.

Even if you fix your loop the next problem will be that your input doesn't start with a `(`. So after reading `Animal` your loop will exit.

The third problem is your output. You don't flush `cout` when you are done.
Also: Why do you use `long long` for `i`? `std::vector::size()` returns `size_t`. So please stick with that.

One "easy" solution would be something like this:

```
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int cb = 0, ob = 0;
    string c;
    vector<string> s;
    while((ob==cb && ob==0) || ob!=cb)
    {
        cin >> c;
        if (c == "(")
            ob++;
        else if (c == ")")
            cb++;
        s.push_back(c);
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << s[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

One other thing: This code won't work if the parenthesis won't match (endless loop or premature break) and won't handle text behind the last closing parenthesis.

As your question isn't really specific about what you want my answer is just for showing you the main problems.

I would also suggest that you check your input stream for errors.